# Unable to open Visual Studio Installer project built by VS2015 in VS2017

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installation, visual-studio-2017

When I try to open an Installer Project (built by Visual Studio 2015) in Visual Studio 2017, I receive this incompatibility error :

> This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following
>   projects. The project types may not be installed or this version of
>   Visual Studio may not support them.

How can I convert it to most recent version of Installer Project?

Comment: create a new blank installer project in VS2017 and use diff tools to see what changed between 2015 & 2017 in the project file.

Answer (score 1):

Built-in support for installer projects was removed in VS2012.  Still available as an add-in from the gallery, which you no doubt used in VS2015.  You'll have to do that again for VS2017.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects